# Display bundle product child items images on cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, product-images, bundled-product

I want to show bundle product child items images on a cart page, in the following place:

[image]

I checked the checkout/cart/item/default.phtml, I think from following line that data is displaying :

```
<?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['value'] ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First copied from

```
app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Helper/Catalog/Product/Configuration.php
```

file and put it to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Bundle/Helper/Catalog/Product/Configuration.php
```

After replace code from function **getBundleOptions()**

```
public function getBundleOptions(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Configuration_Item_Interface $item)
    {
        $options = array();
        $product = $item->getProduct();

        /**
         * @var Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Type
         */
        $typeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance(true);

        // get bundle options
        $optionsQuoteItemOption = $item->getOptionByCode('bundle_option_ids');
        $bundleOptionsIds = $optionsQuoteItemOption ? unserialize($optionsQuoteItemOption->getValue()) : array();
        if ($bundleOptionsIds) {
            /**
            * @var Mage_Bundle_Model_Mysql4_Option_Collection
            */
            $optionsCollection = $typeInstance->getOptionsByIds($bundleOptionsIds, $product);

            // get and add bundle selections collection
            $selectionsQuoteItemOption = $item->getOptionByCode('bundle_selection_ids');

            $bundleSelectionIds = unserialize($selectionsQuoteItemOption->getValue());

            if (!empty($bundleSelectionIds)) {
                $selectionsCollection = $typeInstance->getSelectionsByIds(
                    unserialize($selectionsQuoteItemOption->getValue()),
                    $product
                );

                $bundleOptions = $optionsCollection->appendSelections($selectionsCollection, true);
                foreach ($bundleOptions as $bundleOption) {
                    if ($bundleOption->getSelections()) {
                        $option = array(
                            'label' => $bundleOption->getTitle(),
                            'value' => array()
                        );

                        $bundleSelections = $bundleOption->getSelections();

                        foreach ($bundleSelections as $bundleSelection) {
                            $qty = $this->getSelectionQty($product, $bundleSelection->getSelectionId()) * 1;
                            if ($qty) {
                                $option['value'][] = $qty . ' x ' . $this->escapeHtml($bundleSelection->getName())
                                    . ' ' . Mage::helper('core')->currency(
                                        $this->getSelectionFinalPrice($item, $bundleSelection)
                                    );
                            }
                        }

                        if ($option['value']) {
                            $options[] = $option;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $options;
    }
```

**TO**

```
public function getBundleOptions(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Configuration_Item_Interface $item)
    {
        $options = array();
        $product = $item->getProduct();

        /**
         * @var Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Type
         */
        $typeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance(true);

        // get bundle options
        $optionsQuoteItemOption = $item->getOptionByCode('bundle_option_ids');
        $bundleOptionsIds = $optionsQuoteItemOption ? unserialize($optionsQuoteItemOption->getValue()) : array();
        if ($bundleOptionsIds) {
            /**
            * @var Mage_Bundle_Model_Mysql4_Option_Collection
            */
            $optionsCollection = $typeInstance->getOptionsByIds($bundleOptionsIds, $product);

            // get and add bundle selections collection
            $selectionsQuoteItemOption = $item->getOptionByCode('bundle_selection_ids');

            $bundleSelectionIds = unserialize($selectionsQuoteItemOption->getValue());

            if (!empty($bundleSelectionIds)) {
                $selectionsCollection = $typeInstance->getSelectionsByIds(
                    unserialize($selectionsQuoteItemOption->getValue()),
                    $product
                );

                $bundleOptions = $optionsCollection->appendSelections($selectionsCollection, true);
                foreach ($bundleOptions as $bundleOption) {
                    if ($bundleOption->getSelections()) {
                        $option = array(
                            'label' => $bundleOption->getTitle(),
                            'value' => array()
                        );

                        $bundleSelections = $bundleOption->getSelections();

                        foreach ($bundleSelections as $bundleSelection) {
                            $thumbnail  = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($bundleSelection, 'thumbnail')->resize();  
                            $imageUrl   = '<img src="'.$thumbnail.'" width="75" height="75"/>';
                            $qty = $this->getSelectionQty($product, $bundleSelection->getSelectionId()) * 1;
                            if ($qty) {
                                $option['value'][] = $imageUrl.' '. $qty . ' x ' . $this->escapeHtml($bundleSelection->getName())
                                    . ' ' . Mage::helper('core')->currency(
                                        $this->getSelectionFinalPrice($item, $bundleSelection)
                                    );
                            }
                        }

                        if ($option['value']) {
                            $options[] = $option;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $options;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got help from [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18539/customize-cart-view-with-product-bundle-options) link.

I have copied

```
app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Helper/Catalog/Product/Configuration.php
```

file and put it to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Bundle/Helper/Catalog/Product/Configuration.php
```

Then made required changes to `getBundleOptions()`